# Passing a Bash Array Element to an Awk Regex Expression

Tags: regex, arrays, bash, variables, awk

I've found several questions on how to pass variables from `bash` into `awk`, most notably the `-v` command, but I can't quite seem to get them to do what I want.

Outside the script, the command I'm running is

```
awk '$2 ~ /^\/var$/ { print $1 }' /etc/fstab
```

Which searches `/etc/fstab` for JUST the `/var` partition, and should either print out the physical mount point, or if there isn't one, nothing at all.

Now inside the script I have an array that contains numerous partitions, and what I want to do is iterate through that array to search fstab for each physical mount point. The problem comes in at the fact that the elements in the array have a `/` in them.

So what I want to do (In horrifically incorrect awk) is:

```
PARTITIONS=(/usr /home /var tmp);
for ((n=0; n<${#PARTITION[@]}; n++)); do
    cat /etc/fstab | awk '$2 ~ /^\${PARTITIONS[$n]}$/ { print $1 }';
done
```

But I know that that's not correct. The closest I have right now is:

```
PARTITIONS=(/usr /home /var tmp);
for ((n=0; n<${#PARTITION[@]}; n++)); do
    cat /etc/fstab | awk -v partition="${PARTITIONS[$n]}" '$2 ~ /^\/var$/ { print $1," ",partition }';
done
```

Which at LEAST gets the partition variable into awk, but doesn't help me at all with matching it.

So basically, I need to feed the array in, and get the physical partitions back out. Eventually the results will be assigned to another array, but once I get the output I can go from there.

I also understand awk can remove the need for the cat at the beginning, but I don't know enough about awk to do that yet. :)

Thanks for any help.

**EDIT**

```
cat /etc/fstab | awk -v partition="${PARTITIONS[$n]}" '$2 ~ partition { print $1 }'
```

Approximates what I needed enough to be useful. I was focusing far too much on including the regex apparently. If anyone else could clean this up, it would be much appreciated :)

Comment: As a side note, I've also tried using ENVIRON[${PARTITIONS[$n]}] inside the regex, but that made awk very unhappy.

Comment: You can't pass arrays through the environment. You can pass scalar variables, but they need to be exported in the shell (script). The syntax in AWK for accessing the variable would be `ENVIRON["varname"]` (no curly braces or dollar signs).

Comment: @DennisWilliamson do you have a reference for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk -v partition="${partitions[$n]}" '$2 ~ "^/" partition "$" { print $1 }' /etc/fstab
```

You can concatenate your regex characters (`^` - beginning of string and `$` - end of string) and the slash which is part of the partition name and the variable containing the partition name by placing them adjacent to each other. You don't need to use the slashes that delimit hard-coded regexes.

AWK will accept the filename as an argument without using `cat` to pipe it or using `<` to redirect it.

I recommend using mixed or lowercase variable names in the shell as a habit to avoid potential name collisions with shell or environment variables.

Comment: Thank you so much! and I didn't even think about the collision potential, I'll drop back down to lower case. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 2):

You could also pass the whole array into `awk` through `-v`, this assumes that the directory names do not contain spaces:

```
PARTITIONS=(/usr /home /var /tmp)
awk -v partition="${PARTITIONS[*]}" \
  '$2 != "" && partition ~ $2"\\>" { print $1 }' /etc/fstab
```

This avoids the need for a `for` loop.

#### Explanation

- `partition="${PARTITIONS[*]}" passes in the whole array as space separated string.
- `$2 != ""` means no empty lines are matched.
- `partition ~ $2"\\>"` matches `$2` to the passed in string, `\\>` requires the match to be at the end of a word.

Answer (score 1):

First, to get the most annoying thing out of the way (GUoC), `awk` can work on a file just like `cat`, so just pass it directly. You can't pass whole arrays via `-v` unflattened, but since you're iterating over the items, it doesn't matter. If you want to avoid `-v`, you can pass bash variables by directly including them into awk scripts, you just have to be careful about the quoting (whitespace and awk's own $variable usage). Examples:

```
awk '$2 ~ "'${PARTITIONS[$n]}'" { print $1 }' /etc/fstab
```

Or the more complicated version with soft quotes:

```
awk "\$2 ~ /${PARTITIONS[$n]//\//\\/}/ { print \$1 }" /etc/fstab
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the array on as an additional file to awk, using bash's process substitution.

```
partitions=( /usr /home /var /tmp )
awk '
    FNR==NR { partitions[$0]=""; next } 
    $1 !~ /^#/ && ($2 in partitions) { print $1 }
' <(printf '%s\n' "${partitions[@]}") /etc/fstab
```

NR holds the current number of records (lines) read, and FNR holds the current number of records read in the current file, so FNR==NR is only true when reading the first file, which is the process substitution in this case. So you fill up the partitions array for the first file.

Then, for the second file, you just check if the second field is in the array...

In this case though, I'd just use bash (version >= 4.0), since `/etc/fstab` is typically fairly small.

```
declare -A 'partitions=([/usr]= [/home]= [/var]= [/tmp]=)'
while read -r spec file vfstype mntops freq passno; do
    [[ $spec != \#* && ${partitions[$file]+set} ]] && echo "$spec"
done < /etc/fstab
```

Or depending on the actual goal, you could parse `df`, which will tell you what filesystem the directory is on.

```
dirs=( /usr /home /var /tmp )
for dir in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    { read -r; read -r part _; } < <(df -P "$dir")
    echo "$part"
done
```

Comment: df actually is leaps and bounds ahead of what I was trying to do. I'm now using df to get the filesystems. Thank you for the detailed explaination and additional help. I would have never thought of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
awk -v partitions="${PARTITIONS[*]}" '
    BEGIN { split(partitions,a," ") }
    { for (e in a) { if ($2 ~ a[e]) { print $1 } } }' /etc/fstab
```

So you don't need to create a `for` cycle outside `awk` and this means fewer processes.

Comment: `if ($2 ~ e)` should rather be `if ($2 ~ a[e])`. `e` is the numeric index of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some observations that may help.

If the input is just a single file, it isn't necessary to `cat` it to anything. That is:

```
$ cat file | program # would normally just be ...
$ program < file
```

If you need to feed something complicated to `awk(1)`, then maybe you do have a use case for `cat x | y` ... you could do something like ...

```
(echo StartFlag ${PARTITIONS[*]}; cat /etc/fstab) | awk ...
```

And finally, for the best results on SO ask in a format like ...

1. My PARTITIONS bash variable contains *simplified example contents*
2. Suppose my /etc/fstab contains *simplified example fstab*
3. How do I get the following output: *exact desired output based on simplified input*
4. This is what I've tried: *some people won't just provide code, it helps to ask for assistance on a specific programming problem where you have tried to reach a solution*